# Is it possible to view the server.js file without being the owner?

Tags: node.js, security

Now, I'm not talking about being able to see it in the console source tab. I'm saying how hard is it to get the server.js file and change it to exploit the website? Should I add any added security to the server.js file or is it fine as is?

Thanks!

Comment: You can see if the service you are using is open source and find it on github. If a service leaks its source it's usually a mistake.

Comment: I'm not trying to get someone else files and break their website lol. I'm asking if I should completely disregard security on the server file. I don't want anyone getting into it

Comment: A properly configured server will not let any outside agent have access to the server-side source files.  But, a poorly configured server can have that problem.  So, your server has to be properly configured to not allow such access.  That includes the security settings on the server host itself and it includes how your server process serves files.

Comment: @OwenOdroski you should never disregard security if security is a concern.

Comment: How can I properly configure my server? I'm using node.js with glitch (hopefully moving away from that in the close future)

Comment: By default this can't happen, unless you did something really strange. It's hard to know if you made mistakes without doing a security review. If you generally just want to have a better idea on what kind of security issues might exist, OWASP is a good resource to start studying.

Comment: @Evert I have functions in the server.js file that could make people get a free premium account if ran once. I just want to make sure that no one can access it.

Comment: @OwenOdroski like I said, unless you did someting weird normally this is not an issue. But I can't guarantee that without doing a security review.

Comment: It's also generally considered not good that people could circumvent your security by just looking at your source. (this is called security through obscurity). Even if I read every line of code, i should not be able to get a free premium account. If I can, something is wrong.

Comment: Ok, this is something that I'll work on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some people have said there is already built-in security so that people can not see your Node.js server file. OWASP is a great source if you want to improve the security of your websites.

Thank you to @Evart and @jfreind00 for helping me out!